# Dozer : Field overwritten with source value after being successfully converted

Tags: java, spring, mapping, javabeans, dozer

I'm experiencing a very strange behavior with Dozer. I have a complex type with 2 attributes that need to be merged into a String, nothing crazy.

Here's my converter :

```
@Component
public class CatalogEntryRequestRDToStringConverter extends DozerConverter<CatalogEntryRequestRD, String> {

    public CatalogEntryRequestRDToStringConverter() {
        super(CatalogEntryRequestRD.class, String.class);
    }

    public CatalogEntryRequestRDToStringConverter(Class<CatalogEntryRequestRD> prototypeA, Class<String> prototypeB) {
        super(prototypeA, prototypeB);
    }

    @Override
    public String convertTo(CatalogEntryRequestRD source, String destination) {
        if (source != null) {
            return ConverterUtil.concatenateCodeAndVersion(getParameter(), source.getCode(), source.getVersion());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CatalogEntryRequestRD convertFrom(String source, CatalogEntryRequestRD destination) {
        return null;
    }
```

Here's how I map those types :

```
mapping(StartBorderRequest.class, StartBorderRequestMessageType.class)
        .fields("request.scopeModifiers", "scopeModifiers")
        .fields("request.collectedData", "collectedData")
        .fields("request.selectedResponseData", "selectedResponseData");


mapping(com.test.types.CollectedDataRequestType.class, com.test.message.CollectedDataRequestType.class)
    .fields("tcnType", "tcnType", fieldMappingBuilder -> {
        fieldMappingBuilder.customConverter("CatalogEntryRequestRDToStringConverter");
        fieldMappingBuilder.customConverterParam("tcnTypeId");
    });
```

The converter works. It's being called correctly and the conversion is successful. However, after some debug I noticed that the set method of the destination field is called again at the end of the mapping process with the value of the toString() method for CatalogEntryRequestRD. My correctly converted field is therefore overwritten with the source.toString(). It guess it must have something to do with how Dozer creates the list of fields to map ?

Has anyone ever experienced something like that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure this is the issue, but it could be related to wildcard mapping.  In your mapping specification, can you add TypeMappingOptions.wildcard(false) and see how that changes things?